# Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'dbplyr'

Tags: r, database, tidyverse, dbplyr

The function below is part of a package that I am creating:

```
#' From Dremio Dataset to Tidy Dataframe
#'
#' @export
dataset_to_tibble <- function(query, db_params) {
  
  query <- dbplyr::sql(query)
  
  channel <- do.call(DBI::dbConnect, c(odbc::odbc(), db_params))
  on.exit(DBI::dbDisconnect(channel))
  
  ds_lazy <- dplyr::tbl(channel, query)
  
  dplyr::collect(ds_lazy)
}
```

It works fine but, when I load the package, the message below appears:

```
# > Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'dbplyr':
# >  method         from
# >  print.tbl_lazy     
# >  print.tbl_sql
```

How could I use the {`dplyr`}/{`dbplyr`} functions inside it without triggering this message?

Comment: How are you registering `dplyr`/`dbplyr` in your package? Requires, imports, suggests?

Comment: @GregorThomas Both as imports